# Laravel eloquent eager loading `has-many` relationship with providing how many to load?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I know I can use the `with` method to eager load relationships. But how to determine "how many to load"?

For example, a `Post` model has many `Comment`, I want to load only 5 comments ***per post***. Because a post could have thousands of comments I don't want to load them all. How could I do this?

If I can't do this with Laravel eloquent, what would a raw SQL would be for such a usecase?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways.

1. Making the relationship itself limit the results.

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class)->limit(5);
}
```

2. Using a closure when eager loading to limit the results

```
Post::with(['comments' => function ($query) {
    $query->limit(5);
})->get();
// or
Post::with(['comments' => fn($query) => $query->limit(5)])->get();
```

The second approach is better in my opinion.

[Eloquent Relationships - Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

EDIT

According to [this comment](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4835#issuecomment-674510330), you can limit the results but the syntax isn't very pretty.

```
Post::with(['comments'])->get()
    ->map(function ($query) {
        $query->setRelation('comments', $query->comments->take(5));
        return $query;
    });
// or 
Post::with(['comments'])->get()
    ->map(fn($query) => tap($query)->setRelation('comments', $query->comments->take(5)));
```

It's worth nothing this won't change the relationship query so if 5 posts had a total of a 1000 comments combined, it still queries the database for all 1000 comments.

Comment: Thanks, but you solution won't work, because you limit the total number of comments to 5, what I want to achieve is that every post get 5 comments.

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a workaround I found on github.